# How do I hook onto suite:start / end with Buster.js?

Tags: javascript, buster.js

I want to create a global setup/teardown method with Buster.js, but I can't understand how to do it. The documentation speaks of a "[suit:start](http://docs.busterjs.org/en/v0.7.x/modules/buster-test/runner/#suite-start-event)" and "suite:end"-event which looks like what I'm after, but I don't understand how to hook onto it. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That documentation shows the internal API of the buster-test module. We should probably make it clearer in the docs when stuff is internal.

Currently there's no global setup/teardown, unfortunately.